# Out of range double dimension array

Tags: c#, arrays

Techies--
This code works when I have a single channel or when I have an even split. It *almost* works when I have a remainder...in that it will create the next channel and it will pull in the item, but then goes out of range. These lines are the heart of the trouble:

```
    items_per_batch = batchcount / (int)channels; //
    subsets = batch.Split(items_per_batch);
```

items_per_batch is really used to give the Split extension an idea of a general number on how many items to split by. If it sees a remainder, it just creates another subset array. What i really need to do is keep track of the length of items. I tried:

```
    int idx2 = subset.GetLength(1)
```

At one point, but the forloop using that value also went out of range. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
    static void channelassign()
    {
        int THRESHOLD = 2;
        string[] batch = new string[]
        { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4","item5","item6","item7" };
        int batchcount = batch.Count();
        int items_per_batch;
        string[][] subsets;
        int idx1;
        int idx2;


        if (THRESHOLD != 0) //avoid accidental division by 0.
        {

            float channels = batchcount / THRESHOLD;
            if (channels < 1)
            {
                channels = 1; // only 1 channel is needed
                items_per_batch = batchcount; // process all items
                idx1 = 1; // fix value to a single channel
                idx2 = (batchcount - 1); // true start of array is 0
                subsets = batch.Split(batchcount); //splits correctly
            }
            else
            {
              // decide how many items will be included per batch
              channels =  (int)Math.Round(channels, 
                  MidpointRounding.ToEven); //determines channel number
              items_per_batch = batchcount / (int)channels; //
              subsets = batch.Split(items_per_batch); 
              idx1 = subsets.GetLength(0); // gets channel# assigned by split
              // idx2 = subsets.GetLength(1); // gets items back from splits

            }

            //distribute contents of batch amongst channels


            for (int channel = 0; channel < idx1; channel++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < items_per_batch; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Channel:" + channel.ToString() + " 
                       ItemName: {0} ", subsets[channel][i]);
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Threshold value set to zero. This 
               is an invalid value. Please set THRESHOLD.");
        }
```

Comment: I see no less than *three* different variable naming conventions in your code.  It's a bit schizophrenic to be honest.

Comment: Without knowing what Split extension method is being used, or you providing the source for it; you haven't provided anything for anyone to go on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division

```
float channels = batchcount / THRESHOLD;
```

is performed on `int`s, so your `float channels` always has an integer value, equal to

```
floor(batchcount / THRESHOLD)
```

But that's not the cause of your problem, that is

```
for (int channel = 0; channel < idx1; channel++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items_per_batch; i++)
```

that if `batchcount` is not a multiple of `channels`, some channels have fewer than `items_per_batch` items. Thus the inner loop then tries to access a `subsets[channel][i]` that doesn't exist.

Comment: true enough--i thought i could control the inner loop with: idx2's value back from the second dimension, but that didn't work. what is your suggestion on controlling the second loop?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < subsets[channel].Length; ++i)`, I suppose? That should work.

Comment: I've lost my mind! This is a jagged dd array. idx2 will never solve for that one! yes, that is it!